# Pinch zoom not working in landscape mode when webview is not full screen

Tags: android, webview, pinch

I have a webview in which a local html page is show. It all works fine , but in landscape mode i can use zoom controls but pinch zoom cannot be done

Please help

Comment: pls tell in which device you got this problem, i mean hdpi or ldpi or mdpi???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had suggested you to create in your
> xml file as layout-land, For Instance
>
> I have myuserinterface.xml file, in
> this file, i had created webview
> component, pls create the same file in
> layout-land, this is for landscape
> mode, and **check your problem exists**
>
> if you had worte for device
> compatibility such as layout-hdpi,
> layout-mdpi,layout-ldpi as
> layout-hdpi-land,
> layout-mdpi-land,layout-ldpi-land

Comment: @xydev: then pls create res/layout-large-land and pls revert back to me if you error still exist, pls replay quickly

Comment: @Sakar Ganesh Sry to say it has no xml files.. all by code... this file is selected only for devices abv 2.1